# How can you create an alias for a dereferenced `this` in c++?

Tags: c++, class, macros, this, alias

Rather than doing this:

```
void Sneed::feed() 
{
     qDebug() << this->seed(); // long
     qDebug() << seed(); // Ambiguous
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this instead?

```
void Sneed::feed() 
{
     qDebug() << t->seed(); // saves 3 
     qDebug() << t .seed(); // saves 4
     qDebug() <<   .seed(); // saves 5
     qDebug() <<   @seed(); // saves 5, makes use of @
}
```

If possible, making the declaration as universal as possible?

The best I can do, is this:

```
#define t *this
```

But this is pretty major namespace pollution, and would even apply outside relevant contexts.

I tend to think `@` would be an optimal solution since as far as I know, `@` has no purpose inside C++ code, although I am unsure if this is possible.

Comment: I'd not do that. Preserving to type 3 additional characters  doesn't seems to be worth the mess.

Comment: `auto& t = *this;`?

Comment: I can't imagine a situation where `seed()` is ambiguous and `this->seed()` isn't (except for templates). Unless you mean "ambiguous to the reader of code", but then literally every other name than `this` is harder to read.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen It is ambiguous to the reader. ` but then literally every other name than this is harder to read.` What do you mean? If you are naming your member variables, `int sneed;` instead of `int m_Sneed;`, then the developer is doing something wrong in my opinion.

Comment: About saving characters: Don't. The program won't run any faster just because you saved a few characters. Make it clear to the reader of the code what you are doing instead. Creating an alias, like `auto& t = *this;` doesn't help readability at all.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Acceptiong that `t` is namespace pollution and this style is highly unorthodox, you are wrong about it not being more readable provided one adjusted themselves to the idea. `for ( int i = this->seed(); i < this->feed(); i++ ) { this->sneed( this->chuck() );` vs  `for ( int i = t.seed(); i < t.feed(); i++ ) { t.sneed( t.chuck() );`

Comment: @NathanOliver Unfortunately that works only at a local scale.

Comment: @Anon the point is that both `this->` and `t.` are redundant and just clutter the code.

Comment: _"... provided one adjusted themselves to the idea"_ - Why not drop `this->` and get used to reading code like it's actually written in 99.9% of the cases instead? ... and the few times you actually _need_ `this->`, just type it out and everyone will understand it.

Comment: @Anon Imagine I come to work at your project. First thing I see is `@foo()` or `t.foo()` sprinkled everywhere. How long do you think does it take to get used to such convention? If I were to guess, at least a month. The more experienced developer, the worse. `t.foo()` is even worse than `@foo()`, because I have to guess what `t` object is and why on Earth did you violate all rules of encapsulation and you access everything of `t` in the loop. And yes, I'm opposed to using Hungarian notation. `m_Sneed` is just noise compared to `sneed`.

Comment: @MarkRansom Its not redundant at all. `this` is an important hint to the developer that the function being called is a member function rather than a global function. Granted that the compiler doesnt really care one way or the other, however code should be written on behalf of the reader.

Comment: For me, "on behalf of the reader" means reducing irrelevant clutter whenever possible. I've been using C++ for many years and haven't had a problem knowing what are members and what aren't.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen While I will agree that some hungarian notation, such as `int * pPointerType` is worth opposing, because a pointer can be inferred by the presence of a `->`, other conventions such as `m_` and `s_` are very useful. The fact that you would make your local variable names indistinguishable from your member variable names, leads to poor readability, and bucks what is otherwise an industry standard. Which if you are willing to buck that standard, then I don't see how your criticism holds water.

Comment: @MarkRansom I would just call that incredulity. I imagine you are also someone who utilizes `auto` in favour of just being explicit with your types. While you and many others may be fine with this, I would argue that you are impeding developers with a more cautious and meticulous temperment, who are very intentional and explicit with the code they write.

Comment: (1) No. (2) No. (3) No. (4) No. Don't bother. Map `this->` to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: It's 2022, we have IDEs and syntax colouring. There's probably even plugin for vim to do that. Even without that, if you KISS your functions, you can see the whole body and remember local variables, the remaining ones are member (you're not using globals, are you?). And "industry standard" is [citation neeed]. But this is turning into a discussion, and SO is no place for discussions about coding guidelines.

Comment: @TedLyngmo  The proposition that `99.9%`  of functions called inside classes are members, I would say in my experience is not true, espicially working with other's code. Also, in order for a principle to work, it has to be applied consistently. I dont enjoy arbitrarily using `this` for some member functions, and leaving it blank for others. It makes more sense to just consistently use `this` so one can easily identify when global functions can be used.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Re: Industry Standard -- Qt uses and explicitly reccomends this convention. Re: IDE -- If code requires an IDE to be readily accessible to a reader, then it is poorly written code and should be rewritten. The reason for this is that a good chunk of code we end up reading, is done outside of an IDE, such as documentation, a git repository, or SO code.

Comment: I never said code should require IDE to be readable. I said that adhering to KISS principle and naming your variables properly should make it obvious what is local and what is member, without visual guides like syntax highlighting or noisy `m_` prefixes.

Comment: @Anon Re: _"The proposition that 99.9% of functions called inside classes are members ..."_ - I never made such a claim. What I meant was that if you look at all the C++ projects in the world, you'll find that nearly all of them do not use `this->` to access members.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen There is no obvious way to name a variable to imply that it is a member variable as opposed to a local variable, other than using the m_ prefix. Also you have the wrong impression if you believe that "prefixes" are noisy, because by that principle, you might as well be advocating python's approach who do not have noisy types nor noisy qualifiers such as const.

Comment: @Anon Re: _"I dont enjoy arbitrarily using `this` for some member functions ..."_ - then don't do it arbitrarily. Do it only when it's needed as I said.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Its always needed though to make it immediately obvious that it is a member.

Comment: @Anon If most people agreed with you I'm pretty sure most projects would actually use `this->` to access members instead of how it is Today where very few projects does.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That is an `ad populum` argument, is is generally quite poor, and often an ad hominem. Just because a lot of people are bad programmers, and perpetuate bad practices, does not justify said practices or decisions. Even if a person is an accomplished programmer, does not mean that the code that they write is as easily readable and accessible as it should be. My argument does not depend upon how popular it is; it is just a logical inference that one can immediately determine membership via `this->`.

Comment: @Anon It's not an ad populum argument. I'm not saying that it's correct just because most people and projects do not use `this->`. I'm saying that if most people agreed with you, you'd see more projects using `this->` to access members. See the difference?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Its a distinction without a difference. It has no relevance to the quality of the argument. It shouldnt be brought in as a point of centention.

Comment: I brought it up that because if you want people to change how they write code, you need to take it into account that the vast majority of people don't agree with you that reading code without `this->` is a problem.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen `seed()` could be a global function. Or would you write that as `::seed()`?

Comment: @Anon There are an unlimited number of ways to differentiate member and local variables. Just like `m_` for member variables you could use `v_` for local variables. A common alternative to a `m_` suffix for members is a `_` prefix.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I've never seen that, but I am heavily in favour of prefixes in general. I use f_ for files, d_ for directories, db_ for databases, mn_ for magic numbers, p_ for processes, and g_ for global. I might use others if they are a significant part of a library i am developing, like j_ for javascript scripts.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do that in standard C++ is a macro like you mentioned.

```
#define t (*this)
```

It is not possible to overload `@`. It is also not possible to use it as identifier (so no `#define @ (*this)`). `this` is a context-specific keyword, so you can't create a global reference that keeps this context.

Outside of macro, the only way to have `t.foo()` interpreted as `this->foo()` in every context would be modifying compiler itself to turn that into an extension (an illegal one, since it disallows `t` as an identifier).

Comment: #define @ (*this)    A macro `t` would be very intrusive to code as that is a common variable name. The Op mentioned `@` with the hope no code uses it so defining a macro `@` would be relatively save.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow `@` is not actually a valid identifier in standard C++. If it is allowed, then only by compiler extension (and I don't think any do). See also https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2558r1.html.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow `@` is not a valid identifier, you can't define macro with such name. I believe you could use an emoji or something from Unicode (if compiler supports it), but that's even more cursedIMO.

Comment: That is indeed the problem with the idea of @.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with C++23 you can use explicit object parameters to write

```
void Sneed::feed(this Sneed& t)
```

and it will (mostly) then behave exactly as you want for `t.seed()`. But in exchange you will not be allowed to use `this` in the function anymore.

(Whether or not that is a good idea is a different question.)

(I say mostly, because such a function can not be called on a rvalue, it is equivalent to `void Sneed::feed() &`, not `void Sneed::feed()`. A second overload with `this Sneed&& t` would be needed to forward to the former to get the old behavior. Alternatively `this auto&& t` can be used but has a bit of a different meaning, e.g. it makes the function a template and will give `t` the derived class type if called through one.)

---

Before C++23 `auto& t = *this;` in the function body has the same effect.

Comment: @anon AFAIK, only MSVC has implemented this so far.